# what happen when a materialized is too large in postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, materialized-views

I know that "Materialized view" is a way to cache the result of query in Postgres. However, if this result is too large, how will Postgres handle it? Does this affect the overall performance of the database?

Comment: You get a disk full failure: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/disk-full.html

Answer (score -1):

The data of the materialized view get stored on disk, just like the data in a table. So if the result set is large, it will occupy much space on the data disk. The amount of memory available will influence the speed of creating and using the materialized view, but it doesn't limit its size.